# How to scale font size in iOS?

Tags: ios, fonts, size, scale

I have a problem in font scaling in different iOS devices like iPhone 4, 4S, 5, 5S, 5C, 6, 6 Plus using objective C in XCode 6. Is their any formula to scale automatically on all the devices if I use one constant font in one device lets say in 6 plus.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to open the Storyboard and click on the control, and in the Attributes Inspector find the Font field, and there is a + button to the left of it.

You can use that to add custom constraints based on the size class of the device.

From XCode click on Window->Documentation and API Reference then search for Changing the Font for a Size Class